# Avoid duplicate legends in broken_barh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created Gantt chart,I am trying to add the legend to my plot

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=[['A','B','7:00:00','7:30:00'],['A','C','8:00:00','8:30:00'], 
      ['X','B','7:30:00','8:30:00'],['X','C','7:30:00','8:00:00'],
      ['P','Q','7:30:00','8:30:00'],['P','C','9:00:00','9:30:00']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['L','M','stime','etime'])
start_time=[]
end_time=[]
for i,row in df.iterrows():
   a=row['stime'].split(':')
   b=row['etime'].split(':')
   start_hrs=int(a[0])+(int(a[1])/60)+(int(a[2])/3600)
   end_hrs=int(b[0])+(int(b[1])/60)+(int(b[2])/3600)
   start_time.append(start_hrs)
   end_time.append(end_hrs)
df['start']=start_time
df['end']=end_time
df['diff']=df['end']-df['start']
color = {"B":"turquoise", "C":"crimson","Q":"orange"}
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))   
w=[]
for i, task in enumerate(df.groupby("L")):
   w.append(task[0])
   for r in task[1].groupby("M"):
      data = r[1][["start", "diff"]]
      ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i-0.4,0.8), color=color[r[0]],label=r[1]
       ['M'])
ax.set_yticks(range(len(label)))
ax.set_yticklabels(label)
ax.set_xlabel("time [hrs]")
ax.set_ylabel("L")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

the legends are duplicate in the plot.How can I correct this?

Comment: What do you expect the legend to look like?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this code is very complex and should be streamlined...

However, a first hint might be to put groupname and group right in the loop definition into two different variables instead of indexing over the tuple:

```
...
for lbl, grp in task[1].groupby("M"):
    data = grp[["start", "diff"]]
    ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i-0.4,0.8), color=color[lbl], label=lbl)
...
```

That said, I can give you a possibility to add only labels to legend, that were not already used.
The idea is to initialize an empty list `lbl_pool` to keep track if a label was already used for legend. If jes, put an underscore in front of the label, which surpresses being shown in the legend:

```
w=[]
lbl_pool = []
for i, task in enumerate(df.groupby("L")):
   w.append(task[0])
   for lbl, grp in task[1].groupby("M"):
      data = grp[["start", "diff"]]
      if lbl in lbl_pool:
          prefix = '_'
      else:
          lbl_pool.append(lbl)
          prefix=''
      ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i-0.4,0.8), color=color[lbl], label=prefix+lbl)
```

Result:

[image]

However, that still makes not a cean, readable code out of the whole program; I think it's getting even worse, as it's an additional patch of type "code until it does what it should, no matter of structure"...

I definitely recommend you to review the whole thing and perhaps recreate it from scratch, using the lessons learned you had with this version for a better next one.

*(And just for interfacing with almost all others coding in python: Use 4 spaces as indents, not only 3.)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer,This solved my problem.Ya sure I will try to make it more simple